# Joomla seblod content template

Tags: joomla

We are using joomla 3.4.1 with seblod 3.5

We're trying to make a form in SEblod to make a article, we want a image on the right side of the article with some text next to it and text under it

[image: This is houw we want it]
We have tried to make it work but we just wont get the results, does anyone know how to make this and which fields me need to use.

If you guys need more info just ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEBLOD actually has heaps of resources to answer this on their website. This manual I think is particularly useful to you.

http://www.seblod.com/resources/manuals/designer/drag-drop-templating

Basically:

1. Create your image upload field
2. Create your text fields
3. Put your main text in the "mainbody" position
4. Put your image in the "Rightbody-a" position
5. Put your text to go under your image in the "Rightbody-b" position